# requests.get(URL) results showing blank in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

The below script is returning blank,

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://fortune.com/fortune500/amazon-com/')
r.text
```

My actual intention is I want to extract Revenues ($M), Profits ($M), Assets ($M) and other useful information available in the above link. Please guide me on the same.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Copy pasting your code works for me.

Comment: Your code works fine

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your proxy or firewall

Comment: Thanks all, I tried r.content but python shell get stuck. Can we export results to csv?

Comment: @faithon We can't reproduce your problem. Your code works. There is something else happening on your end that we the readers cannot determine.

Comment: @idjaw, thanks for response. I tried to solve it but could not get through issue. r.content works for me but it takes time. Is there anyway to export results to csv file? I edited my question with my actual intention, could you please help on the same.

Comment: you could check if your python shell or ide ur using needs to be run as administrator if ur using windows. And also whether there is a secure connection issue.

Comment: @Dev_Man, I am using windows 10 with i7 &16GB RAM and running IDE as administrator, still when I display r.content she'll get stuck.

Comment: maybe passing a `user-agent` would help? try: `r = requests.get('http://fortune.com/fortune500/amazon-com/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36'})
`

Comment: have you tried checking `r.status_code` to make sure you're connecting properly?